# Numpy Append to Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I’m building a project for the Raspberry Pi that turns a relay on and off random times in a specific time window. To manage the time slots, I want to use a two-dimensional array that’s generated daily. So, my Python application needs to empty the previous day’s array, and populate it with the on/off time slots being generated randomly. I can’t figure out how to append my time values to the array. Can someone  help me?
Here’s my code:

```
  daily_slots = np.empty([1], dtype=[('onTime', np.dtype(int)), ('offTime', np.dtype(int))])
  # numpy populates the array with whatever is in memory at that time,
  # so delete the existing, 'empty' array row
  daily_slots = np.delete(daily_slots, 0, 0)
```

With that in place, how do I append values? The numpy documentation says I should do something like the following:

```
daily_slots = np.append(daily_slots, [700, 800])
```

But that’s not working, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./controller.py", line 351, in <module>
    init_app()
  File "./controller.py", line 128, in init_app
    build_daily_slots_array()
  File "./controller.py", line 307, in build_daily_slots_array
    daily_slots = np.append(daily_slots, [700, 800])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 3555, in append
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

I've tried everything I can think of and I've poked and prodded at the numpy documentation and I've not found the answer.

Am I not declaring the array correctly?  I want each array 'row' to consist of a two-element array (the ontime and offtime).

Comment: numpy append is verry slow, since numpy guarantees continuous memory. Use python list instead.

Comment: You probably just want a list. Or, if you really want a numpy array of some random values, use `np.random`. You almost never want `np.append`. And your approach doesn't make much sense. You initialize an `empty` array, then delete a row, then append a row... that isn't how you should be using numpy.

Comment: Neither of those responses help me solve my problem. Suggesting alternative approaches isn't answering the question and doesn't help.

Comment: I'm deleting the row, because numpy for some ridiculous reason puts that row in there, with dummy data, when I initialize the array. I can't find any way to initialize the array to empty, otherwise I'd do that.  I'm not looking for a way to generate random data, I am trying to find a way to store random data I've created in a two-dimensional array.  This is supposed to be a place where I can get answers to my questions. I laid out what I'm trying to do, I explained myself, and I showed my code. Will you please help me answer my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.append` uses `np.concatenate`.  It isn't a true copy of list append.  It turns the new value into an array and does concatenate.  **But to do concatenate with structured arrays, all arrays have to have the same dtype**  (or at least compatible ones, hence the 'promotion' error.

This works:

```
In [4]: np.append(daily_slots, np.array((700, 800), dtype=daily_slots.dtype))
Out[4]: 
array([(  0, 1075970048), (700,        800)], 
      dtype=[('onTime', '<i4'), ('offTime', '<i4')])
```

This also works.  I had to add the `[]` so that the 2nd array was 1d like the first.  Without them it is 0d - in effect that's all that `np.append` adds to the game.

```
In [6]: np.concatenate((daily_slots, np.array([(700, 800)], dtype=daily_slots.dtype)))
Out[6]: 
array([(  0, 1075970048), (700,        800)], 
      dtype=[('onTime', '<i4'), ('offTime', '<i4')])
```

For growing and shrinking, a list is usually better.  In this case a list of 2 element tuples, or may be a list of a custom class.

If it is a list of tuples, you could wrap it in `np.array` to turn it into a 2d array for ease of doing calculations.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question instead of ignoring my question and simply telling me not to do what I want to do. You're helping me solve my problem and learn a bit about numpy at the same time. I'm really struggling to understand why that's the only types of answers you get on StackOverflow  lately.